# Enviar un parámetro en una Action de Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Tengo estos botones agrupados en mi componente de VUE

```
<template>
 <MDBBtnGroup v-model="tipo_operacion" class="shadow-0">
   <MDBBtn active color="light" value="1" @click="tipoOperacionAction(value)">Comprar</MDBBtn>
   <MDBBtn color="light" value="2" @click="tipoOperacionAction()">Alquilar</MDBBtn>
   <MDBBtn color="light" value="3" @click="tipoOperacionAction()">Emprendimientos</MDBBtn>
 </MDBBtnGroup>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  computed:{
    ...mapState(['tipo_operacion'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('filtros', ['tipoOperacionAction'])
  },
  components: {
    MDBBtnGroup,
    MDBBtn,
  },
 };
</script>
```

Y quiero que al clickear cualquiera de esos botones, cambie un valor en el Store de VUEX

```
state: {
    tipo_operacion: 1
},
mutations: {
   setTipoOperacion(state, payload) {
       state.tipo_operacion = payload;
    }
},
actions: {
   tipoOperacionAction({ commit }, value) {
       console.log(value)
    }
}
```

-> Yo espero poder imprimir en consola 1,2 o 3, depende del botón que yo aprete.
Pensé que podría enviar algún parámetro a través de la acción, pero no sé como hacer referencia al elemento en el que hago click, para así extraer el valor `value` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor forma de hacer esto es que no repitas el código y utilices un `v-for` de vue para generar variantes de un elemento según un arreglo de data que tengas

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      buttonsData: [{
          value: 1,
          label: "Comprar"
        },
        {
          value: 2,
          label: "Alquilar"
        },
        {
          value: 3,
          label: "Emprendimientos"
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    logData(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="data in buttonsData" :key="data.value" :value="data.value" @click="logData(data.value)">
        {{ data.label }}
      </button>
</div>
```

Si esto no te convence mucho también puedes pasar como argumento directamente en la función el valor estático que quieras evaluar, por ejemplo así:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    logData(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button value="1" @click="logData(1)">Comprar</button>
  <button value="2" @click="logData(2)">Alquilar</button>
  <button value="3" @click="logData(3)">Emprendimientos</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo habia resuelto pasando ``tipoOperacionAction($event)`` y recibiendo ``$event.currentTarget`` en mi ``store``, pero definitivamente esta debe ser la manera de hacerlo aplicando correctamente los principios de los fw reactivos. A veces me olvido de las herramientas que tengo y quiero resolver las cosas como si estuviera en jQuery. Muchisimas gracias.